# Why my Texmaker cannot generate PDF output

Tags: texmaker

I am using Texmaker to write my thesis. Previously it can generate PDF output if I click `Quick build`. So I can view my PDF output and make changes if required. 
Now my Texmaker does not generate PDF after I write or make changes. Only when I close down Texmaker and re-open the document again, I can see my PDF output. So, I have to close and open repeatedly everytime I make changes to see the output.

Why is this happening? Do I need to make some changes in the settings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you are talking about TeXMaker. If you go to `Options -> Configure Texmaker`, then click on `Quick Build`, make sure you have selected one of the options that ends with "View PDF". Does that solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Texmaker 5.0, latest version released july 17 was bugged.

**Author fixed this bug within Texmaker 5.0.1** two days later.

Problem no longer exists when Quick build runs with latex+dvips+ps2pdf+viewpdf.

Answer (score 0):

My approach to solve the problem:

1. Uninstall MiKtex.
2. Uninstall Texmaker
3. Reinstall Miktex
4. Upgrade Miktex
5. Set environmental variable both for command line and Gui: https://miktex.org/howto/modify-path
6. Reinstall Texmaker
7. Restart PC.

Answer (score -1):

You have messed with environment variables in your PC. Probably that's the reason your installation wont help. So here is what you have to do:

My computer > right click > Properties > Advanced System settings > Environment Variables > in system variables click on "Path" > click edit (copy the address already in the path variables into a text document, in case things go wrong, you can put the old address back) > and give the path where MiKTeX is installed e.g. I had

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\;
```

Don't forget to put a semicolon > click OK in all the windows > Open TexMaker back and then run > Done.